# Is centrifugal force a conservative force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect, conservative-field

The centrifugal force depends on the position so it must be a conservative force whereas the Coriolis force depends on the velocity and it is a non-conservative force.

Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: Centrifugal force depends on velocity.

Comment: A conservative force is a force with the property that the work done in moving a particle between two points is independent of the taken path. Therefore consider moving your particle along a defined path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centrifugal acceleration of a point *A* located at $\mathbf{r}_A$ with linear velocity $\mathbf{v}_A$ riding on a body with rot. velocity $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is

$$ \mathbf{a}_A = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \mathbf{v}_A $$

If the center of rotation *C* is at $\mathbf{r}_C$ then the linear velocity is $\mathbf{v}_A = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_A-\mathbf{r}_C)$ which makes the centrifugal term

$$ \mathbf{a}_A = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \left(  \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_A-\mathbf{r}_C)\right)$$

A centrifugal force is *only* defined at the center of mass *G*, and it is not a vector field like centrifugal acceleration.

$$ \mathbf{F} = m\, \mathbf{a}_G = m \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \left(  \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\mathbf{r}_G-\mathbf{r}_C)\right) $$

So your question is mute because this force *does no work* and hence cannot be classified as conservative or not.

Comment: The standard definition of conservative force is a force whose work is independent of the path. Then the centrifugal force is conservative (same for magnetostatic force on a particle). It is not a conservative field though.

Comment: Centrifugal force is an inertial conservative force provided the angular velocity is constant in time, it acts on every point in a reference frame rotating with respect to an inertial reference frame. The proof of conservativity is elementary.

Comment: ευχαριστω για την απαντηση Thank you for the answer. You must also answer to the comments

Comment: @veronika Παρακαλώ. Ευχαρίστηση μου.